# Cant load mecab in java windows

Tags: java, mecab

I'm trying to use mecab library in java on windows. I've installed a prebuilt mecab library for windows. When I try to load it like

```
try{
    System.loadLibrary("libmecab");
}catch(Exception e){
    // print stack trace
}
```

it throws a following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.chasen.mecab.MeCabJNI.new_Tagger__SWIG_0(Ljava/lang/String;)J
at org.chasen.mecab.MeCabJNI.new_Tagger__SWIG_0(Native Method)
at org.chasen.mecab.Tagger.<init>(Tagger.java:140)
```

I've added mecab on library path

```
-Djava.library.path="c:/mecab/bin"
```

I can access Mecab from windows command prompt. Has anybody faced a similar problem and resolved the issue? Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: I've never tried using the MeCab–Java SWIG bindings, so I can't help you exactly with this, but I have used Kuromoji, which implements the exact same algorithm as MeCab but in native Java and JVM-friendly APIs, with most/all the same dictionaries available, and works great: https://github.com/atilika/kuromoji

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll have a look.